# Android Spinner: white text on white backrground

Tags: android, colors, spinner

I got two people with Motorola phones comlaining that my spinners have white text on white background. Since I only hane a HTC I'm not able to reproduce this.

Has anyone got in that problem and solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a default layout for your spinner and items and they will be equal on each phone.